# Mapbox.js: parsing coordinates into latitude and longitude from GeoJSON

Tags: geojson, mapbox

I am making my way through learning Mapbox and Mapbox.js. I have loaded my GeoJSON data from a URL:

```
var featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer()
.loadURL('./data_frag.geojson')
.addTo(map);
```

Now I am trying to parse out the lat and lon coordinates. It makes sense to me to try something like:

```
var longitude = featureLayer.geometry.coordinates[0];
var latitude = featureLayer.geometry.coordinates[1];
```

but that is not right.

Should I be using the feature layer or the GeoJSON layer for this?

Comment: have you tried using the [Filter Function](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.2.1/l-geojson/) 
`filter(
<GeoJSON> featureData,
<ILayer> layer )
Function that will be used to decide whether to show a feature or not.`

Comment: I'm looking for a way to parse the combined lat lon coordinates in the GeoJSON file I've loaded into their individual lat and lon points so that I can use L.latLng as in this example: 

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/dynamically-drawing-a-line/. 

I am also confused about the difference between a featureLayer and a GeoJSON layer as in 

https://www.mapbox.com/guides/master-web-map-layers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`L.mapbox.featureLayer()` has a [getGeoJSON method](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.2.3/l-mapbox-featurelayer/#section-featurelayer-getgeojson). For the first feature in the GeoJSON FeatureCollection:

```
var longitude = (featureLayer.getGeoJSON()).features[0].geometry.coordinates[0];
var latitude = (featureLayer.getGeoJSON()).features[0].geometry.coordinates[1];
```